# where are the common member variables stored when defining a class?

Tags: c++, class, c++11

I define a simple class：

```
class A
{
public:
    int a;
};
```

the `sizeof(A)` is 4, so I am confused that where the common member variable `a` is stored when I just define such a class? stack or heap?

Comment: A `class` is a "blueprint" - you need an instance to know where the data is stored. Also this is really more about storage duration, since the C++ standard does not define "stack" and "heap" requirements

Comment: Besides there aren't such concepts like stack or heap allocation in the c++ standard, this will depend on how that class is instantiated and where it's memory is allocated.

Comment: @UnholySheep so why does the class take up 4 types?

Comment: What do you mean by types? 4 is the size of a regular integer.

Comment: If sizeof int is 4, then it's 4, it doesn't magically change, remember that `sizeof` preforms its operation at compile time.

Comment: Think about `sizeof(int)` or any `sizeof(T)`. Declaration doesn't take memory. Instances do.

Comment: @Jarod42 But it is a definition of class A rather than a declaration;

Comment: @Jarod42 but `int a;` is a definition which system allocate memory for

Comment: `int a;` is different than `int` or `using myInt = int;`. Same for `struct S{};` and `struct S{} myObject;` or `S s;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not stored anywhere. It only receives a place in memory when you actually create an object of type `A`.

```
int main()
{
   A obj1; // obj1.a will be on the "stack"
   A* pObj2 = new A; // pObj2->a will be on the "heap"
}
```

Comment: I do not mean the method of creating a object.         If the variable a does not stored anywhere, why the class A will take up 4 types?

Comment: @AndrewGong class A doesn't. Its size is 4 - but that tells you the size of the objects when you create them.

Comment: sorry, still do not understand why sizeof(A) is 4 if  class A doesn't take up 4 types as you said. ~~

Comment: @AndrewGong Think of `sizeof(A)` as the amount of storage an object of type `A` would take, regardlessly of what kind of memory it resides into.

Comment: @AndrewGong if I make an architectural sketch of a house, I can say that its size would be 5 meters, however there isn't any actual size of the house until I build it.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore but `int a;` is a definition which system will allocate memory for

Comment: @AndrewGong Well, obviously not if it is done inside a class declaration. I mean, if it were, all member variables would be static, right? And now think about a class template. Also has members, obviously, but one might never instantiate the class template, so there might actually exist no class at all with that member.

Comment: @AndrewGong the term "definition" has different meanings when associated with a variable and with a class. That might be where the confusion comes from. When you define a variable, you're correct that you also specify where in memory it will reside. A class definition is simply a "declaration" if you will. It just defines the layout and the interface.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore yes, you really know my confusion and your this answer is very good. but if  `a` is assigned `1` like `class A {
 int a = 1;
};`,  is the var `a` still a declaration?

Comment: @AndrewGong yes, that'd just be a default value.

Comment: `obj1.a will be on the "stack` `...the heap` ... To be very fastidious, there aren't such things like stack or heap at the language level. A compiler is actually allowed to place all objects on the actual heap and solely "simulate" a stack (automatic storage duration).